# Indexes of strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

My current project has me converting Ruby into Node.js. I've never worked with Ruby before this and so I'm still trying to learn all the syntactical differences. Currently, I'm a bit confused about this snippet:

```
      myUri = Addressable::URI.parse(original_path)
      idx = original_path.index(myUri.path)
      hit.props[:path] = original_path[idx..original_path.length-1]
    else
      hit.is_invalid = true
```

So, I understand that we are parsing the `original_path`.

Then, we are getting the index of the `myUri.path` inside of the `original_path`, which I believe will return a number.

The next line is what's confusing me. I know I'm setting `[:path]` to something, but I don't understand what. I think that it's a modified version of `original_path` but I'm not understanding how its being modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`original_path[idx..original_path.length-1]` accesses string using a range.

See a range exaple

```
(1..4).to_a
# [1,2,3,4]
```

Range string/array access takes a part of the array/string that is between range boundaries. In this case - between `idx` (that is the beginning of `myUri.path`) and the end of the string.

See below:

```
a = 'abcd'
# => "abcd"
a[1..a.size-1]
# => "bcd"
```

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)